# Firefox not connected with Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have a problem with Selenium and Firefox.  The error log shows:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"43.0","st":1449744438000}},"app-system-share":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"d":"/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com.xpi","e":false,"v":"3.2","st":1442597111000}}}
1452507695529   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1452507695530   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1452507695530   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
```

I'm using Firefox 43.0, Selenium 2.48.2, and Ubuntu OS.

Any suggestions for making webdriver work with Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla is working towards requiring all Firefox Add-ons/Extensions to be signed in order form them to be installed. See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing.

Firefox 43 has a preference in about:config that allows you to disable this requirement. In your code, you will need to set the profile parameter xpinstall.signatures.required = false.

This worked for me in Java with Selenium 2.49.0 and Firefox 43.0.4:

```
FirefoxProfile oProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
oProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
WebDriver oWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(oProfile);
```

Firefox 44 will remove the xpinstall.signatures.required preference and it will be required for you to get your Add-on/Extension signed.